# No startup for Jenkins installation over CentOS 7

Tags: jenkins, centos7

I've been following those instructions in order to install Jenkins over CentOS 7
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#red-hat-centos

$ sudo systemctl start jenkins

> jenkins.service not found

But nos service seems to be installed, no WAR is found anywhere. I don't get it.
Does anybody have an idea of what I could have forgotten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so Jenkins wasn't installed indeed, due to GPG signature check.
I just didn't dig Yum's response... Shame on me.

So I changed the install command accordingly:

> yum --nogpgcheck install jenkins